# Python how to "ignore" ascii text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape some stuff off a page using selenium. But this some of the text has ascii text in it.. so I get this.

```
    f.write(database_text.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 1462: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I was wondering, is there anyway to just simpley ascii?

Thanks!

```
print("â")
```

I'm not looking to write it in my text file, but ignore it.
note: It's not just "â" it has other chars like that also.

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

nmber_one = 1
f = open(str(unique_filename) + ".txt", 'w')
for i in range(5, 37):
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr""" + "[" + str(i) + "]" + """/td[2]/a""").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[nmber_one])
    nmber_one = nmber_one + 1
    database_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/pre")
    f = open(str(unique_filename) + ".txt", 'w',)
    f.write(database_text.text)
    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)



import uuid
import io
unique_filename = uuid.uuid4()
```

which generates a new filename, well it should anyway, it worked before.

Comment: Do you mind providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some of the text **is not** ascii. `database_text.text` is likely unicode text (you can do `print type(database_text.text)` to verify) and contains non-english text. If you are on windows it may be "codepage" text which depends on how your user account is configured.

Often, one wants to store text like this as `utf-8` so open your output file accordingly

```
import io
text = u"â"
with io.open('somefile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

If you really do want to just drop the non-ascii characters from the file completely you can setup a error policy

```
text = u"ignore funky â character"
with io.open('somefile.txt', 'w', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

In the end, you need to choose what representation you want to use for non-ascii (roughly speaking, non-English) text.

Comment: Hmm... okay, how would I put that in my code though? I updated my question w/ most of the script.

Comment: First, `import io` and then where you currently do `f = open(...)` replace that with `f = io.open(...)` and the `encoding` and `errors` policy you want.

Comment: I thought you were doing python 2 but just noticed you tagged it 2 and 3. In pythnon 3, the default `open` works the same way as `io.open` in python 2. And in 3 , `str` is unicode while in python 2 `str` is ascii and `unicode` is unicode.

Comment: One more problem though, It's only creating one text file, I want it too create has many as my loop needs

Comment: I can only see you example code so this may be a bit vague... but you do `f = open(str(unique_filename) + ".txt", 'w')` in the loop... since that variable never changes, it keeps creating the same filename over and over. You need to generate a unique name in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Edited by post, please check.

Comment: Okay, i don't know what is in `unique_filename` but how about `f = open('{}-{}.txt'. format(unique_filename, nmber_one), 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

A Try Except block would work:

```
try:
    f.write(database_text.text)
except UnicodeEncodeError: 
    pass
```

Comment: but this doesn't write the text which I suspect the user wants to do.

Comment: True, it would not. I didn't realise how he was actually running this thing. Nice work on the answer @tdelaney